# Generate a regex for the following pattern

Tags: java, regex

Build a regex to match "${0} and ${1} or ${2}"

**Condition**

Must have $ followed by {} braces with only digits 0-9. There can be only one such pattern in the string. If there are more than one such patterns then a space followed by either AND or OR can be there.

After OR or AND the same ${} pattern should be present with only digits between the brackets.

Have tried the following `\$\{\d*\} | OR | AND | \s+`

Comment: Your verbal description is impossible to understand. Edit, and provide examples, what should match and what not.

Comment: This is not a Java regular expression, and it matches (badly) parts of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to form a single regex without logical regex OR operator to match a complete line.

```
^\$\{\d{1,3}\}(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+\$\{\d{1,3}\})*$
```

Since `$` is a special character in regex, you need to escape it in-order to match a literal `$` symbol.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eE9bZ7/2)

**OR**

```
^\$\{\d{1,3}\}(?:\s+(?:and|or)\s+\$\{\d{1,3}\})+$
```

This expect atleast one `and` or `or` present inbetween the `$` symbols.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eE9bZ7/1)

```
String s = "${0} and ${1} or ${2}";
System.out.println(s.matches("^\\$\\{\\d{1,3}\\}(?:\\s+(?:and|or)\\s+\\$\\{\\d{1,3}\\})*$"));
// true
```

Comment: Yes the first one was working correctly. Sorry. This is my first question. I have updated the question.